# How fopen file in Users dir from www dir (wamp)?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I trying to fopen a dir in Users dir ("C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\SOFTWARENAME\")
I trying do that from a php file that located in www dir (wamp folder in C).
This is my try:

```
$file = fopen('../../../Users/Myusername/AppData/Roaming/SOFTWARENAME/', 'r');
```

I get "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

Help?

Thank and sorry for my english.

Comment: And where is the file?

Comment: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\SOFTWARENAME\

Comment: Fopen opens a file not a directory

Comment: Sure, the file is there.
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\SOFTWARENAME\FILENAME

Comment: If that's the case, you need to specify the filename as well as the folder name. Your code above doesn't include `FILENAME`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its generally considered a bad idea to try to access files outside of the root directory of the web application and it may even be completely blocked by php unless you turn off a security check.

But that being said, you can try to use an environment variable to get the full path.

Check out this api for example: [$_ENV](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)

So your code may look more like this:

```
$file = fopen($_ENV['HOMEDRIVE'] + $_ENV['HOMEPATH] + '/' + fileName, 'r');
```

I'm not sure whats in the environment exactly but those are common environment variables on windows.